# Problems with document id retrieved in firestore - React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I researched here in the community, Google and in the react and firebase documentation, but for some days now I have this problem and I don't know how to solve it. I'm having trouble adding likes to multiple firestore documents.
I can make a call to my componentDidMount () and get all the document IDs to add them to the likes function.

My problem is:
I can only add likes to the first document of this collection, to the other documents I cannot make it recognized by the specific ids of each document.

Example: I have 3 documents with 0 likes, but I want to add a like on item 3, by clicking on the like button on document 3 in my jsx, the like is added to document 1, the same if it was done for document 2 and so onwards. I can only add a like to the first document in my collection regardless of where the click was made to add likes. how do i dynamically recognize which document this tanning is being added to?

if anyone can help me i will be very grateful, because i have this problem for about two weeks.

state:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Posts = [],
      idDoc = [],
      ids = "",
      isliked: false,
    }
```

get Id documents:

```
componentDidMount() {     
        firebase.firestore().collection("newPost").orderBy('createdAt', 'desc').onSnapshot( snapshot => {
          let Posts = [];
          let idDoc = [];
          let ids = "";

          snapshot.forEach( doc => {
          Posts.push(doc.data());    
          idDoc.push(doc.id);       
          ids = (doc.id);        
          });  

          this.setState({Posts: Posts});
          this.setState({idDoc: idDoc});  
          this.setState({ids: ids});
        });
       }
```

Like Function:

```
UplikeFunc() {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName;
    let isliked = this.state.isliked;
    let ids = this.state.ids;

    if(isliked && this.state.corDoLike === 'white') {
      this.setState({   
        likesCount: firebase.firestore().collection('newPost').doc(ids).update({         
          likes: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(user),
          LikeColor: 'rgb(87, 151, 87)' // add collor in button like
        }) + 1,
          isliked: false                           
        });        
          this.setState({corDoLike: 'rgb(87, 151, 87)'});
          console.log('Like  + ');    
      } else {
        this.setState({          
          likesCount: firebase.firestore().collection('newPost').doc(ids).update({          
            likes: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(user),
            LikeColor: 'white' // add collor in button like
          }) - 1 ,
            isliked: true
          }); 
          this.setState({corDoLike: 'white'});
          console.log('Like  - ');    
      }      
    }
```

JSX code:

```
{this.state.Posts.map((itens,index) => {
             return (               
                  <div className="viewPost-content" key={index}>                    
                    <div className="viewPost-box" style={{backgroundColor: itens.colorBg} } >   
                        <p> <Moment to={itens.createdAt.toDate().toString()} /> </p> 
                        <button id="PostDelete" onClick={this.deletePost}> <ion-icon name="ellipsis-horizontal-sharp"></ion-icon> </button>                
                        <h2 className="text-post"> {itens.texto} </h2>                  
                        <div class="viewPost-icons">
                          <div style={{marginRight: '-5px', backgroundColor:'transparent'}}>
                            <button id="bt-Posts" 
                            onClick={ () => this.abrirComent() }>
                              <ion-icon name="chatbox"></ion-icon>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                          <div style={{marginLeft: '-15px'}}> {itens.comentarios.length} </div>

                          <div style={{marginRight: '-5px'}}>
                            <button id="bt-Posts" onClick={() => this.UplikeFunc(this.corLike)}  
                              value={this.state.corDoLike} 
                              style={{color: itens.LikeColor}}>
                              <ion-icon name="thumbs-up-sharp"></ion-icon>
                            </button>
                            </div>  
                          <div style={{marginLeft: '-15px'}}> {itens.likes.length} </div>

                          <div style={{marginRight: '-5px'}}>
                            <button id="bt-Posts" onClick={() => this.UpdislikeFunc(this.corDislike)}
                              value={this.state.corDoDislike}
                              style={{color: itens.DislikeColor}}
                              >

                              <ion-icon name="thumbs-down-sharp"></ion-icon>
                            </button>
                            </div>
                          <div style={{marginLeft: '-15px'}}> {itens.dislikes.length} </div>                          
                        </div>
                    </div>                
                  </div>
                )
              })
          }
```

like button:

```
<div style={{marginRight: '-5px'}}>
      <button id="bt-Posts" onClick={() => this.UplikeFunc(this.corLike)}  
           value={this.state.corDoLike} 
           style={{color: itens.LikeColor}}>
             <ion-icon name="thumbs-up-sharp"></ion-icon>
      </button>
 </div>  
    <div style={{marginLeft: '-15px'}}> {itens.likes.length} </div>
```

firestore:

[image]

Comment: this.corLike in this.UplikeFunc(this.corLike) is a function that adds color to the like button if it gets a like.

Comment: You seem to have a *lot* of uses of functions that return a *promise* in synchronous code... (hint:  ALL firestore calls are asynchronous)

Comment: "
Add comment
As LeadDreamer pointed out the firestore API calls are designed as asynchronous. You can refer to this [link](ttps://medium.com/@vladfr/use-cloud-firestore-with-async-bce875af0183) To better understand the firestore API call and sample to better understand the firestore API call and sample,"

Comment: I will read about it

Comment: I'm still having the same problem. I can get all the document ids but I can't find a way for my post deletion function to identify which post is being deleted specifically. every time I run my function, it only deletes the first document created in the collection. already tested to return the ids to a string, but still deleting only the first document created, I can't find a way to recognize which document is being deleted by the id. if i remove the index [0] from idDoc, i get an error from firebase saying that they only accept arguments in .doc () of type string –

Comment: i'm not really understanding how to get a specific id for the firestore and use it in my jsx correctly.